# Issues using Kafka rest config option consumer.instance.timeout.ms provided in the documentation

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

Kafka rest proxy fails when trying some of the parameters provided in the confluent docs.
When tried with parameters like `consumer.instance.timeout.ms` which is provided in documentation[https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/config.html] fails.

**Request**

```
curl -X POST http://172.16.x.x:8082/consumers/onerp -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" -d '{"name": "ins-b", "format": "binary", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest", "auto.commit.enable": "false", "consumer.instance.timeout.ms": 180000}'
```

**Response**

```
{"error_code":422,"message":"Unrecognized field: consumer.instance.timeout.ms"}
```

However, request with minimum config options succeeds:

```
curl -X POST http://172.16.x.x:8082/consumers/onerp -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" -d '{"name": "ins-b", "format": "binary", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest", "auto.commit.enable": "false"}'
```

I'm running a recent version of confluent platform 5.5.1 on docker with only zookeeper, kafka, schema-registry and rest-proxy services. 
Is this not the correct way of using the configurations options or is there any other way to use these config options?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation that you linked to (and the `consumer.instance.timeout.ms` parameter, specifically) is for the Kafka REST Proxy server itself.

Only a subset of options are supported for allowing a consumer to configure itself via the API and those are listed in [the API reference](https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/kafka-rest/api.html#post--consumers-(string-group_name)).